# FIREBASE WARNING: auth() was canceled: Auth token is expired

Tags: firebase, firebase-security

I'm using FirebaseSimpleLogin with email/password authentication and the rememberMe option set to true. I am able to login and logout fine. Security rules work. Everything is fine. Except, I will occasionally be logged out with the following message showing up in devtools:

```
FIREBASE WARNING: auth() was canceled: Auth token is expired.
```

Any ideas on what could be causing the auth token to expire? This will sometimes happen multiple times a day while working on the site.

Comment: How long is the expiration time on your tokens? Check the Auth tab in Forge (got to your firebase url in a browser)

Comment: @Kato It is set to 24hrs. I guess this overrides the `rememberMe` option? I also do not see a way of extending the authentication from the client (JavaScript). Any ideas?

Comment: RememberMe tells simple login to store the token and use it again on the next visit (instead of only keeping it for the browser session). The expiration length applies in either case. You don't extend the token's lifespan, just get a new one.

Comment: @Kato is there a way to get a new token for the user without having them login again?

Comment: Sure, you can use [custom login](https://www.firebase.com/docs/security/custom-login.html) and generate your own tokens at any time, in any way you like.